# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).proofreader is not a function

Tags: jquery, joomla

Wanted to use joomla proofreader component, does not display a modal window gives error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).proofreader is not a function` found this line which gives error,

```
<div id="proofreader_container" class="proofreader_container" style="display:none;"><?php echo $displayData['form']; ?></div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#proofreader_container').proofreader({
                'handlerType'       : '<?php echo $displayData['options']['handler']; ?>',
                <?php if (isset($displayData['options']['load_form_url'])): ?>
                'loadFormUrl'       : '<?php echo $displayData['options']['load_form_url']; ?>',
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($displayData['options']['highlight']): ?>
                'highlightTypos'    : true,
                <?php endif; ?>
                'selectionMaxLength': <?php echo $displayData['options']['selection_limit']; ?>
            },
            {
                'reportTypo'           : '<?php echo JText::_('COM_PROOFREADER_BUTTON_REPORT_TYPO', true); ?>',
                'thankYou'             : '<?php echo JText::_('COM_PROOFREADER_MESSAGE_THANK_YOU', true); ?>',
                'browserIsNotSupported': '<?php echo JText::_('COM_PROOFREADER_ERROR_BROWSER_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED', true); ?>',
                'selectionIsTooLarge'  : '<?php echo JText::_('COM_PROOFREADER_ERROR_TOO_LARGE_TEXT_BLOCK', true); ?>'
            });
    })
</script>
```

where not so written?

Comment: Is the `proofreader` file included?

Comment: @eisbehr I don't know... I just installed it as an extension

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you need to include the plugin file into your page too. But I can't help you with joomla there.

Comment: @eisbehr in the manual only install extension
 Download the distribution component and save it to your local computer.
In Joomla admin select extension Manager -> Install.
Click choose file and Select the archive with the distribution component stored on the local computer.
Click Download and install.